# Kafka Parallel Consumer is not splitting work between different processes

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka

I am using [confluent parallel-consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) in order to acheive fast writes into different Data stores. I implemented my code and everything worked just fine locally with dockers.
Once I started several hosts with several consumers (with the same group id) I noticed that only one of the nodes (processes) is really consuming data. The topic I am reading from has 24 partitions, and I have 3 different nodes, I expected that kafka will split the work between them.

Here are parts of my code:

```
fun buildConsumer(config: KafkaConsumerConfig): KafkaConsumer<String, JsonObject> {
    val props = Properties()
    props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = config.kafkaBootstrapServers
    props[ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = "earliest"
    props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "myGroup"
    // Auto commit must be false in parallel consumer
    props[ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG] = false
    props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java.name
    props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = JsonObjectDeSerializer::class.java.name
    val consumer = KafkaConsumer<String, JsonObject>(props)
    
    return consumer
}

private fun createReactParallelConsumer(): ReactorProcessor<String, JsonObject> {
    val options = ParallelConsumerOptions.builder<String, JsonObject>()
        .ordering(ParallelConsumerOptions.ProcessingOrder.KEY)
        .maxConcurrency(10)
        .batchSize(1)
        .consumer(buildConsumer(kafkaConsumerConfig))
        .build()
    return ReactorProcessor(options)
}
```

And my main code:

```
    pConsumer = createReactParallelConsumer()
    pConsumer.subscribe(UniLists.of(kafkaConsumerConfig.kafkaTopic))
    pConsumer.react { context ->
        batchProcessor.processBatch(context)
    }
```

Would appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We hit an issue that was closed in version 0.5.2.4 https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer/issues/409

The Parallel client kept old unfinished offsets, since our consumer was slow (many different reasons) we got to the end of the retention (earliest strategy), so every time we restarted the consumer, it was scanning all those incompatible offsets (which it did not truncate them - AKA the bug).  Fix was just updating version from 0.5.2.3 to 0.5.2.4